# Unable to make custom syntax highlighting work in TextMate

Tags: php, ruby, editor, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I am trying to highlight a custom language in TextMate. However, the following definition does not highlight PHP insertions (I do select it for my *.serpent files):

```
{ scopeName = 'source.serpent';
 fileTypes = ( 'serpent' );
 patterns = (
  { begin = '<\?';
   end = '\?>';
   patterns = ( { include = 'source.php'; } );
  },
 );
}
```

If I select PHP language, then the PHP parts are highlighted.

What can be the reason? Should it work?

I was also considering ruby insertions with <% %> delimiters, but it doesn't work with the simplest setup.

---

**Update**

Apparently, it is an issue of PHP only. The following language definition highlights Ruby and Serpent languages in my text, but not PHP insertions! What is wrong here?

```
{   scopeName = 'source.phpruby.serpent';
    fileTypes = ( 'serpent', 'serpent.php', 'serpent.erb' );
    patterns = (
        {   begin = '<\?(php|=)?';
            end = '\?>';
            patterns = ( { include = 'source.php'; } );
        },
        {   begin = '<%';
            end = '%>';
            patterns = ( { include = 'source.ruby'; } );
        },
        {   include = 'source.serpent'; },
    );
}
```

I have made it working by replacing source.php with #language in my patterns and by copying the repository from PHP language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On Fri, Jul 9, 2010 at 08:02, **Allan
>   Odgaard** 
>   wrote:
>
> We made the PHP grammar itself match
>   the  construct, so with your
>   grammar, those bits have been consumed
>   by the including grammar, and the
>   included PHP grammar will therefor be
>   a no-op.
>
> The reason we made it this way was so
>   that the PHP grammar can sort of work
>   when used as the root grammar, since
>   lots of users insist on using it that
>   way, despite our efforts¹ to educate
>   ;)
>
> ¹
>   http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/PHPSyntaxHighlight

With the help of the God, I understood my mistake and was able to make a working (at least highlighting!) definition:

```
{   scopeName = 'source.phpruby.serpent';
    fileTypes = ( 'serpent', 'serpent.php', 'serpent.erb' );
    patterns = (
        {   begin = '<\?(php|=|)';
            end = '\?>';
            include = 'source.php';
        },
        {   begin = '<%';
            end = '%>';
            patterns = ( { include = 'source.ruby'; } );
        },
        {   include = 'source.serpent'; },
    );
}
```

Comment: There was a not working code for a short while, but then it was fixed.